# Gray globe (earth) appears after restart for no apparent reason - might something be wrong?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, security

I restart my MacBook Air OSX 10.8.5 every few days as a routine habit. Twice in the last few months it has come back with the globe (earth) image displayed for 20-30 seconds (I believe it was flashing), then continues on to start normally. See sequence of images.

The first time was immediately after removing some software which displayed my screen via WiFi to a projector at a company (downloaded earlier from the projector mfr. website). Second time nothing particular except that I only had 3GB of remaining disk space at the time.

Should my computer/OS ever display the globe image spontaneously? Is this something that "just happens" sometimes, or should I be looking for a cause?

[image: blinking start-up globe (off)]
[image: blinking start-up globe (on)]
[image: normal start-up apple]
[image: log-in screen]

Answer (score 2):

This means your Mac is trying to start up using files on your network instead of the copy of macOS on the hard drive which there is none so your Mac is stuck in a temporary loop.

When it's done, it gives up and boots from local files on the hard drive. Try turning on Airplane mode before the restart to prevent the globe from showing up.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've never intentionally tried to start up from files on a network, never even considered it. Under what circumstances would my laptop try to do so on its own? This sounds like it could be a security issue.

Comment: Nah, just a messed up boot order. See my edit to the other answer on resetting NVRAM. Hopefully it’s not because your drive is failing and more likely the setting needed to be re-saved to NVRAM to boot first from your Os disk.

Answer (score 2):

This is what happens when a Mac can’t find the internal bootable drive and falls back any NetBoot server, but there is no server to connect to.

You can reset your boot order by resetting the NVRAM. In the past this was called parameter RAM, which is why P and R are held down at startup.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063

Network boot used to be a feature of OS X Server, then [Server.app on macOS](https://support.apple.com/macos/server). Now Internet Recovery handles this for current hardware.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it gives me something to think about! Does this suggest that my laptop may very rarely, spontaneously, try to boot via network, but usually not? I try to never have WiFi turned on when I log out or shut down, but I can't 100% guarantee it never happens. Would that affect the behavior?